# What is the Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.?

Tags: android, xml, flutter, debugging, android-manifest

## Error debugging a Flutter shopping app

**Please help me find the error. I am debugging an already created flutter project**

This is the Error Message after running **flutter run**:

```
$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     J:\Personal\Projects\E-commerce-App-UI-Flutter\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27: error: resource style/LaunchTheme (aka com.example.shop_app:style/LaunchTheme) not found.
     error: failed processing manifest.
```

This is the referenced **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shop_app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <!--
         Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--
     io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here.
    -->
    <application
        android:name="com.example.shop_app"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:label="shop_app" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.shop_app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >

            <!--
                 Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI.
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!--
                 Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame.
            -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
             Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />
        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is **GitHub Repo** I cloned this project
[E-commerce-App-UI-Flutter](https://github.com/abuanwar072/E-commerce-App-UI-Flutter)

I debugged most of the errors but I am not able to run this code